# Subtract values of columns from two different data frames in PySpark to find RMSE

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I am not able to figure it out. I am trying to calculate the RMSE between test and prediction data.

test

```
col1    col2
 a        2 
 b        3
```

prediction

```
col1   col2
 a       4 
 b       5
```

I am trying to do this test(col2)-prediction(col2). That is

```
2-4 =-2
3-5 =-2
```

I tried

```
test.select("col2").subtract(prediction.select("col2"))
```

But I am not getting the required result. I am trying to obtain this result to find the RMSE. Is there a built in function in spark to find the RMSE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a join and an arithmetic subtract :

```
test.join(prediction, on="col1").withColumn("sub", test.col2-prediction.col2)
```

Comment: Thank you. So without joining we cannot do the arithmetic subtraction right?

Comment: without join, you cannot compare the line X in test with the line X in prediction. [`subtract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.8/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract) will compare dataframe test to dataframe prediction remove the lines from the first one existing in the second one.

Answer (score -1):

Please replace your table names in below expression:

```
tab1.join(tab2).withColumn("Sub", tab2("T1")-tab1("T")).select("Sub").show()
```

Comment: Although it's in Spark Scala.. you can go something like thin is pyspark