# How to compare two dataframes and calculate the differences in PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have two dataframes and I am trying to write a function to compare the two dataframes so that it will return me the net changes to columns that are impacted.

DF1:

```
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| City          | Temp | Zone | Score | Activity |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| Atlanta       | 10   | 1    | 100   | 400      |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| Chicago       | 100  | 2    | 200   | 500      |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| Boston        | 100  | 3    | 300   | 600      |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| San Francisco | 1000 | 4    | 400   | 700      |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
```

DF2:

```
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| City          | Temp | Zone | Score | Activity |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| Atlanta       | 10   | 1    | 150   | 400      |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| Chicago       | 100  | 2    | 200   | 450      |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| Boston        | 100  | 3    | 300   | 650      |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| San Francisco | 1200 | 4    | 400   | 750      |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
```

I would like the result to be like:

```
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| City          | Temp | Zone | Score | Activity |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| Atlanta       | 0    | 0    | 50    | 0        |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| Boston        | 0    | 0    | 0     | -50      |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
| San Francisco | 200  | 0    | 0     | 50       |
+---------------+------+------+-------+----------+
```

I am very new to PySpark, and am wondering how can I achieve this in PySpark?

I tried to do `df2.substract(df1)` but it just shows me the row in df2 that was not in df1, which is not very straightforward, if I just want to see **net changes happened to any columns.**

**Notes: City name is the unique identifier**. Each row is different.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtract values of columns from two different data frames in PySpark to find RMSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010335/subtract-values-of-columns-from-two-different-data-frames-in-pyspark-to-find-rms)

Comment: But in my real data, each of the dataframes have many columns, and I want the function to determine/monitor what columns have changes, instead of having to specifically naming it / them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataframe.subtract(dataframe)` is logical subtraction (`EXCEPT DISTINCT`).

[image]

So, instead you can join and do arithmetic subtraction between columns.

```py
df = df1.join(df2, on='City').cache()

for col in df1.columns:
    if col != 'City':
        df = df.withColumn('diff_' + col, df2[col] - df1[col]).drop(col)
```